# Run firebase database operations in the background in onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service

I need to perform some realtime-database operation as soon as firebase onMessageReceived(...) method gets called.

I am able to retrieve the data, however performing a DB operation like read or even update doesn't work when the app is in the background, it only works when its on the foreground.

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

  //some CRUD operation for instance
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
      .getReference("test_node")
      .child("test_child")
      .get() //I've tried replacing this with other CRUDs operation like setValue(...) still doesn't work
      ...
}
```

Any explanation to why this doesn't work or what could I be doing wrong?

**Solutions tried**

```
  -FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)
  -FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
```

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I don't have any errors, I've added logs inside `onMessageReceived` & they're running successfully. The CRUD operations run if the app is in the foreground but once I kill the app, they don't work, the logs still get shown regardless

Comment: Have you tried using WorkManager for running background tasks?

Comment: @Boron Have you tried doing it in a different service? Once data has been received call an update service and pass through the data that you would like set. Also remember, that if an App is in the background and a service is running then a Push Notification style notification has to be used to inform the user that the app is running background tasks. It is referred to as a Foreground service
https://medium.com/huawei-developers/foreground-services-with-notification-channel-in-android-7a272f07ad1#:~:text=A%20foreground%20service%20performs%20some,t%20interacting%20with%20the%20app.

Answer (score 2):

Android has a lot of restrictions when running app in background.
Depending on operating system version it could be possible or not to access file system or do network call when app isn't visible for user.

I think you should use `WorkManager` and run [expedited work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#expedited) in this case.

```
class ExpeditedWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        return ForegroundInfo(
            NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification()
        )
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
          .getReference("test_node")
          .child("test_child")
          .get()
    } 

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        TODO() // create notification here for backward compatibility
    }
}
```

And then you can run it like this

```
val request = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ExpeditedWorker::class.java)
    .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(context)
    .enqueue(request)
```

You can read more about background restrictions in Android [here](https://medium.com/its-tinkoff/android-background-restrictions-b63e73fe508)